# Unable to display and show AlertDialog in BroadcastReceiver in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-broadcastreceiver

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton instance;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    boolean alertDisplayed;

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MySingleton() {

    }

    public void displayAlertDialog(final Activity context) {

        builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final String action = Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS;
        final String message = "Enable either GPS or any other location"
                + " service to find current location.  Click OK to go to"
                + " location services settings to let you do so.";

        builder.setMessage(message).setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                                context.startActivityForResult(new Intent(action), 1);
                                d.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Retry",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int id) {
                                context.finish();
                            }
                        });
        builder.create().show();
        alertDisplayed = true;

    }


    public void dismissDialog() {
        if (alertDisplayed && builder != null) {
            //dismiss dialog
            dismissDialog();
        }
        alertDisplayed = false;
    }
}



 BroadcastReceiver updateBooleanBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("action", true)) {

              //here i want to hide Alert 
            } else {

              //Here i want to display Alert 

            }
        }
    };
```

i have Make class Singlton where i have write code to show and hide method of Alert box and also i have received  Event but i am unable to call Singsong class to show and hide Alert please help me how to get this .

Comment: Please tell me the way we can show dialog and hide dialog i am calling that in Acclivity Broadcast receiver @MikeM.

Comment: i dont have to startActvity i have to Simple show Alert which i declare in SIngltonClass if Location will Off and if Location will On then it will dismissAlert

Comment: I apologize. I misread your code. What class is `updateBooleanBroadCastReceiver` in? Is it in an `Activity`?

Comment: yes its an Activity But still am facing issue i am unable to disapper where Location on

Comment: Then to show the `Dialog`, it should be something like: `MySingleton.getInstance().displayAlertDialog(MainActivity.this);`. Also, you should change `builder` to just an `AlertDialog`, and change the `if` in `dismissDialog()` to something like: `if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) { dialog.dismiss(); }`.

Comment: OK wait let me try

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/36S5fn9gyCi3pwZ5T3qeyRV  @MikeM. please check my code is it ok

Comment: and i have use http://paste.ofcode.org/36zb2nqMhvWuFhq2SpgXYsv this Singlton class

Comment: But Still i am unable to dismis dilog when i On Location what is Problem please tell me should i use Asynktask for this?

Comment: see when i Off location then using ur code and Singlton class i am able to display Alert now if i have On Location  from Notification Manger but Location not disaper

Comment: and both method fire but Alertnot gone when i on Location from Location manger

Comment: Well, the `AlertDialog dialog` should be `static`, too. Other than that, I don't really see how your `BroadcastReceiver` fits into all of this, and I don't know where the broadcast is coming from, so I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: can i send u my code u ll Understand simply

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/JVDDFQDsZ2V7vH4a5htdpX look line number 348 am able to display Toast messge when On and Off Location but i am unable to dismiss alert

Comment: OK let me try this also

Comment: U know dismissDialog method is not calling actully when On Location

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/3PT4nPATPDjSmqkdLKgVSZ this line code not Excuted

Comment: That is not what I suggested, and it's failing because `builder.create()` is creating a new instance each time. Do not keep an `AlertDialog.Builder` variable. Keep an `AlertDialog` variable, set it to `builder.create()` in the `displayAlertDialog()`, and check that for `null` and `isShowing()` in `dismissDialog()`, like I demonstrate in a previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109650/discussion-between-research-development-and-mike-m).